# How to use a method to call various methods inside and return true in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to have a method public boolean verifySignIn() and call below methods inside and return true,

setUserName(String) This method is used to set the username.
setPassword(String) This method is used to set the password.
clickLogin() This method is used to click login button.

here is how my code looks now,

```
public boolean verifySignIn() 
{       
setUserName("user");
setPassword("admin123");
clickLogin();
return true;

}
```

Comment: what is the point of this return value, if it always returns true? also: since what you want is already what you have, what is the actual question?

Comment: in place of return true you should verify either success message or visibility of some element and result of that should be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return **true** from `verifySignIn()` you can wrap the function within a `try-catch{}` block as follows:

```
public boolean verifySignIn() {  
       try{  
            setUserName("user");
            setPassword("admin123");
            clickLogin();
            return true;  
       }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
       }  
}
```

Comment: if the goal is (as the OP explained) to always return true, how does this help?

Comment: @Stultuske Your argument/question makes sense but as per _best practices_ I didn't want to leave out `catch{}`. In-case `setUserName()` or `setPassword()` or `clickLogin` fails ideally we are catching it too and returning _false_.

Comment: my guess would be to propagate the exception, and just making it a void method. if the login fails, you should be somewhat "blocked" anyway, no problem in making it programmatically clear

Comment: But it doesn't have to be any kind of exception, maybe it's just wrong credentials. I agree with @Stultuske, but also I don't agree that this should always be true, there  should be something in middle, catching exception, and also thinking about negative test cases, like as mentioned earlier wrong creds.

Comment: @Stultuske That should have been the best approach but as OP wants to return `true` from the mentioned 3 lines there doesn't seems any other options left

Comment: indeed my point. he wants to return true, yet you alter the code to return false

Comment: @Kovacic Yup,  your words are valid too. I think there is a huge **void** in the question itself. So I took the safest approach to catch the _base exceptation_ and return _false_. Of-coarse the objective of this question needs further clarification

Comment: I agree with You @Debanjan.

Comment: @Stultuske If we return _true_ from `catch{}` that would be [FalsePositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) which is a huge **No** from _Test_ perspective

Comment: @DebanjanB now you are changing the analysis. you claim that it should only return true if the login data was correct. the OP stated it has to always return true.

Answer (score 0):

If I would do something like this, I would do something like this:

```
public boolean verifySignIn(){       
   return clickLogin(email, password);
}
```

method impl.

```
public boolean clickLogin(email, password){
    setUserName("user");
    setPassword("admin123");
    //do some assert, return result
    Assert.assertTrue(); // if it fails, You wont be able to execute any further.
    // or have some kind of check and return boolean

    return true;   
}
```

But anyhow try to use **PageObject** design and instead of returning boolean value .Return Page object (eg. main page) You logged in if everything is ok. 
So You can interact with next page, or just simply check it if You're successfully logged in, and thus extend and modularise Your testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think to verify login the most important thing in this method is to check if clicking on that login button really takes you where you're supposed to get.

So, I'd do a method like:

```
public boolean verifySignIn() {
    setUserName("user");
    setPassword("admin123");
    return clickLogin();
  }
```

And then I'd define the clickLogin() method a bit better:

```
public boolean clickLogin() {
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
    loginButton.click;
    return !driver.findElements(By.id("someElementOnPage")).isEmpty();
  }
```

The solution with try/catch by DebanjanB is good, but the only thing it verifies is that there is no exception. It does not actually verify if the login is taking you to the correct page.